# How to speed up Node js puppeteer typing?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Hello can someone please with puppeteer, The code i have is working but typing long words takes for ever is there a way to speed up typing?

The problem is the typing takes way to long when i have a lot of words in a text file. want a way to just paste from .tx file without typing

````
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())


// Start building links
const links = fs.readFileSync('robux4.txt').toString().split('\r\n');
const finalLinks = links.join().replace(/,/g, '\n');
let halfLinks1 = links.slice(0, 60000);

puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    // Build
    await page.goto('https://www.site.ec.illinois.edu/account/my-account', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
        timeout: 110000,
    });
    await page.waitForSelector('#input_comp-jzxudh31')
    let random1 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(10);
    let random2 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(10);
    let random3 = Math.random(3).toString(36).substring(10);
    await page.type('#input_comp-jzxudh31', random1 + random2 ,)
    await page.type('#input_comp-jzxudh50', random1 + random2 ,)
    await page.type('#input_comp-jzxudh50', '@gmail.com')
    await page.type('#input_comp-jzxudh60', random1 + random2)
    await page.click('._1fbEI')
    await page.waitFor(5000)
    await page.goto('https://www.site.ec.illinois.edu/account/my-account', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
        timeout: 110000,
    });
    await page.waitForSelector('.sAa6lj > #profileVisibility > .sfYIV2 > .s3Fb6T > .s1b4VH')
    await page.click('.sAa6lj > #profileVisibility > .sfYIV2 > .s3Fb6T > .s1b4VH')
    await page.waitForSelector('div > div > .s3xEru > .s1CVDb > .s3UsU7')
    await page.click('div > div > .s3xEru > .s1CVDb > .s3UsU7')
    await page.waitForSelector('#TPASection_k14nm80e > div > div.sHCADR > div > div > section > div > div > div.s3uVoc > div > div.s1Dlxl > button.s1CVDb.s3X1VX.s2uKgn.o3x-IY--upgrade.s2_1ar.oYbiBO--primary')
    await page.click('#TPASection_k14nm80e > div > div.sHCADR > div > div > section > div > div > div.s3uVoc > div > div.s1Dlxl > button.s1CVDb.s3X1VX.s2uKgn.o3x-IY--upgrade.s2_1ar.oYbiBO--primary')
    await page.waitForSelector('#display-name-id')
    const input = await page.$('#display-name-id');
    await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })
    await page.waitFor(2000)
    await input.type('FREE ROBUX CODES - HOW TO GET FREE ROBUX [' + random3 + ']');
    await page.waitFor(2000)
    await page.waitForSelector('#TPASection_k14nm80e > div > div.s1bpIa > form > div.s2faAG > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > button.s1CVDb.s3X1VX.s2uKgn.o3x-IY---priority-7-primary.o3x-IY--upgrade.stQWOt')
    await page.click('#TPASection_k14nm80e > div > div.s1bpIa > form > div.s2faAG > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > button.s1CVDb.s3X1VX.s2uKgn.o3x-IY---priority-7-primary.o3x-IY--upgrade.stQWOt')
    await page.waitForSelector('#comp-k14nm5yw > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div')
    await page.click('#comp-k14nm5yw > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div')
    await page.waitForNavigation
    await page.waitForSelector('#TPASection_kkfzu8kj > div > div.s7lnRg > div.s3hIHm.o1DNob--childrenFullWidth > div > div > div.sGjTGl.o2GAvo--withHoverColor > div.sugWin > div.s2neI5.opo9uN---typography-11-runningText.opo9uN---priority-7-primary.s1uyGa')
    await page.waitFor(2000)
    await page.click('#TPASection_kkfzu8kj > div > div.s7lnRg > div.s3hIHm.o1DNob--childrenFullWidth > div > div > div.sGjTGl.o2GAvo--withHoverColor > div.sugWin > div.s2neI5.opo9uN---typography-11-runningText.opo9uN---priority-7-primary.s1uyGa')
    let link1 = halfLinks1.join().replace(/,/g, '\n')
    let content = link1;
    await page.waitForSelector('#placeholder-editor')
    await page.click('#placeholder-editor')
    await page.type('#placeholder-editor', content)
    await page.waitForTimeout(14000)
    await page.click('#TPASection_kkfzu8kj > div > div.s1CcJ8 > div > div > div > section > div > div > div.s2DXU2.s1_fDS > div.s17Yb3 > button.s2cOuO.s1ZhWc.s2lWPV.opZNt_--upgrade.s22DiS.oyXUyw--primary')
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000)
    const link = await page.evaluate(() => location.href);
    fs.appendFileSync('links2.txt', '<a href="' + link + '">FREE ROBUX CODES</a>' + '\n')
    await browser.close();
}) ```
````

Comment: `await page.waitForTimeout(14000)` are pretty concerning from a performance standpoint. Are you sure you need a dozen of these calls? `waitForSelector` and `waitForFunction` give you much tighter bounds, moving your script along as soon as state is prepared rather than causing a race condition. In some cases you can replace `page.type` calls with `$eval(sel, el => el.value = "whatever")` but it depends on the website you're manipulating, whether it needs  to fire trusted events and handlers or not. Why the [tag:c++] tag?